# How to create an ActiveRecord nested hash in the backend?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, hash, sinatra

I have 4 Classes (Song, Review, Artist, and Genre). I'm displaying, on my frontend, a display of songs where each song gets a card. That card displays the reviews for that song, as well as displaying the song's name, the artist who made the song, and the genre that song is. For purposes here, a song can only have one artist and one genre -- unlike the real world.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :songs
  has_many :genres, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres, :songs
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :artists, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :artist
      belongs_to :genre
    
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :genre, :artist, :reviews
    end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
end
```

What I'm looking to do here is set up something my GET requests, on the backend side where I can send a hash that contains the full `Song` and its properties + the `artist.name`, the `genre.name`, and the `reviews` that belong to that `song`.

At bare minimum what I'm looking for is to have `songs.to_json(include: :artist)` and also `songs.to_json(include: :genre)` both in the same line/hash. If I can also have `songs.to_json(include: :reviews)` that would be a bonus.

```
get "/songs" do

    # successfully adds the artist to each song
    songs = Song.all.order(:name)
    songs.to_json(include: :artist)
  end
```

@chiperific shared a great link in the comments below but I'm looking for more info regarding multiple includes, especially sibling types (which `artist` and `genre` are to each other). `reviews` is a child of `song` but `artist` and `genre` are each a parent to `songs`.

Heads up: I'm not using full Rails (as it's for a school project) -- I'm limited to Sinatra and Ruby on the backend.

EDIT: Just want to add some code to clarify my request:

Comment: Shouldn't tag as rails when not rails, tag as Sinatra for a Sinatra answer

Comment: Honest mistake - fixed it

Comment: What about this? https://medium.com/@coywreid/using-include-in-your-sinatra-application-controller-methods-fc42f297b560

Comment: @Chiperific Thank you man! Gonna look into it tomorrow morning because I tried the includes:  here but was running into issues due to tying in two parents who are siblings to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Actually came into an answer via a friend of mine who posted about it here: https://dev.to/nicm/including-associated-data-in-a-sinatra-api-response-4kko

Hope this helps whoever finds this page via Google! Helped solve my issue, cheers.